# Why is my last span breaking my :after styling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm adding `•` after each list items except for the last item. This worked just fine until I added one more span at the end `<span class="more-brands">`. Now my last brand item also has the `•`. How come? [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyoesLdq/).

```html
<div class="brand-list">
    <span class="brand">Haaning and Htoon</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander McQueen</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander Wang</span> 
    + <span class="more-brands">39</span> more brands                           
</div>
```

```css
// All except the last span with class name 'brand'
.brand:not(:last-child):after {
    content: "•";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 3px;    
}
```

Comment: why won't you use <ul><li> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, current CSS has no selector for "the last element with certain class". `.brand:not(:last-child)` means "the element with `brand` class *that is* not last child of its parent" and all your `span`s of class `brand` match this condition.

If your goal is to insert `•` characters *between* `span`s of class `brand`, wouldn't it be more appropriate to insert them *before* each `span.brand` except of the *first* one?

```css
/* All spans with class name 'brand' except the first one*/
.brand + .brand:before {
    content: "•";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 3px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-list">
    <span class="brand">Haaning and Htoon</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander McQueen</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander Wang</span> 
    + <span class="more-brands">39</span> more brands                           
</div>
```

As a bonus, this will work in IE8 (which doesn't recognize CSS3 selectors like `:not()` and `:nth-last-*`)

Comment: Very clever. Thanks Ilya. This is the best explanation and the most elegant solution. PS. screw old browsers. That train left around line 500 of my css :p

Answer (score 2):

`:last-child` selects the last child within a parent. The last child within the parent is your `.more-brands` element. None of your `.brand` elements are the `:last-child`.

To get around this, you can either remove the `span` element around your "39", or use a different element and make use of the `:last-of-type` selector instead.

```css
.brand:not(:last-of-type):after {
    content: "•";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 3px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-list">
    <span class="brand">Haaning and Htoon</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander McQueen</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander Wang</span> 
    + 39 more brands                           
</div>

<p>Or:</p>

<div class="brand-list">
    <span class="brand">Haaning and Htoon</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander McQueen</span>
    <span class="brand">Alexander Wang</span> 
    + <i>39</i> more brands                           
</div>
```

`:last-of-type` works here as this selector selects the last element of a certain type (e.g. `span`).

Comment: Ok, thanks for good explanation. But why does it not consider class name? A parent may have many childs, but only a selected few are to be styled. In my case, I'm using the last span so I can use the number in my JS.

Comment: Because `:last-child` targets specifically *the* last child. In your markup, your last `.brand` element is not the last child.

Comment: Ok, so it does not consider class name at all. Good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `after` and using `not` the last `span` doesn't have the symbol `•` but you want to exclude the last two `span` so:

```css
.brand-list {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.brand {
  color: #557486;
}
.brand-list span:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2)):after {
  content: "•";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-list">
  <span class="brand">Haaning and Htoon</span>
  <span class="brand">J. Lindeberg</span>
  <span class="brand">7 for all Mankind</span>
  <span class="brand">Alexander McQueen</span>
  <span class="brand">Alexander Wang</span> + <span class="more-brands">39</span> more brands
</div>
```

Comment: Although James's answer explains *why* it's not working, your found solution that works and I can still keep my `<span>` tag. Thanks.